# Does any hero with enhanced regeneration in One Punch Man also ages slowly or live longer?

Tags: one-punch-man

In many series, heroes or superhuman people who has enhanced regeneration also age slowly or live longer. Is this the case in One Punch Man? Does any hero with enhanced regeneration in One Punch Man also ages slowly or live longer?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not possible to tell a that point. In OPM, there is really little information about characters background.

I can only assume that you are referencing Zombieman, S-Class rank 8 hero ? There is no clue of the age of this guy, or even when he become an "undead", so maybe he doesn't age, who knows ?

all we know about him is [here](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Zombieman)

Comment: We do have details about his creation, in fact.  Not hard enough to definitively nail down his creation date, but there are some pretty tight bounds from what we know.  The anime hasn't gotten there yet, but the Manga and webcomic have.